# ESP32 MQTT_EVENT_DATA NOT

Tags: azure, mqtt, iot, esp32

I am trying to use arduino-esp32 methods defined in file mqtt_client.h for my project.
I've used this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure/azure-sdk-for-c/how-to-setup-and-run-azure-sdk-for-embedded-c-iot-hub-client-on-espressif-esp32/ example.

My device is connecting to IoT Hub Azure and successfully sends data to it.
My problem is when I'm trying to send a message from IoTHub to device from azure console. The MQTT_EVENT_DATA is not fired.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <WiFi.h>
#include <mqtt_client.h>

#include <az_iot_hub_client.h>
#include <az_result.h>
#include <az_span.h>

#include "AzIoTSasToken.h"
#include "SerialLogger.h"
#include "ca.h"
#include "iot_configs.h"

#define sizeofarray(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))
#define NTP_SERVERS "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov"
#define MQTT_QOS1 1
#define DO_NOT_RETAIN_MSG 0
#define SAS_TOKEN_DURATION_IN_MINUTES 60
#define UNIX_TIME_NOV_13_2017 1510592825

#define PST_TIME_ZONE -8
#define PST_TIME_ZONE_DST_DIFF   1

#define GMT_OFFSET_SECS (PST_TIME_ZONE * 3600)
#define GMT_OFFSET_SECS_DST ((PST_TIME_ZONE + PST_TIME_ZONE_DST_DIFF) * 3600)

static const char* ssid = IOT_CONFIG_WIFI_SSID;
static const char* password = IOT_CONFIG_WIFI_PASSWORD;
static const char* host = IOT_CONFIG_IOTHUB_FQDN;
static const char* mqtt_broker_uri = "mqtts://" IOT_CONFIG_IOTHUB_FQDN;
static const char* device_id = IOT_CONFIG_DEVICE_ID;
static const int mqtt_port = 8883;

static esp_mqtt_client_handle_t mqtt_client;
static az_iot_hub_client client;

static char mqtt_client_id[128];
static char mqtt_username[128];
static char mqtt_password[200];
static uint8_t sas_signature_buffer[256];
static unsigned long next_telemetry_send_time_ms = 0;
static char telemetry_topic[128];
static uint8_t telemetry_payload[100];
static uint32_t telemetry_send_count = 0;

static AzIoTSasToken sasToken(
    &client,
    AZ_SPAN_FROM_STR(IOT_CONFIG_DEVICE_KEY),
    AZ_SPAN_FROM_BUFFER(sas_signature_buffer),
    AZ_SPAN_FROM_BUFFER(mqtt_password));

static void connectToWiFi()
{
  Logger.Info("Connecting to WIFI SSID " + String(ssid));

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");

  Logger.Info("WiFi connected, IP address: " + WiFi.localIP().toString());
}

static void initializeTime()
{
  Logger.Info("Setting time using SNTP");

  configTime(GMT_OFFSET_SECS, GMT_OFFSET_SECS_DST, NTP_SERVERS);
  time_t now = time(NULL);
  while (now < UNIX_TIME_NOV_13_2017)
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
    now = time(nullptr);
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Logger.Info("Time initialized!");
}

void receivedCallback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length)
{
  Logger.Info("Received [");
  Logger.Info(topic);
  Logger.Info("]: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }
}

static esp_err_t mqtt_event_handler(esp_mqtt_event_handle_t event)
{
   Logger.Info("mqtt_event_handler fired!");
  switch (event->event_id)
  {
    case MQTT_EVENT_ERROR:
      Logger.Info("MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_ERROR");
      break;
    case MQTT_EVENT_CONNECTED:
      Logger.Info("MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_CONNECTED");
      break;
    case MQTT_EVENT_DISCONNECTED:
      Logger.Info("MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_DISCONNECTED");
      break;
    case MQTT_EVENT_SUBSCRIBED:
      Logger.Info("MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_SUBSCRIBED");
      break;
    case MQTT_EVENT_UNSUBSCRIBED:
      Logger.Info("MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_UNSUBSCRIBED");
      break;
    case MQTT_EVENT_PUBLISHED:
      Logger.Info("MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_PUBLISHED");
      break;
    case MQTT_EVENT_DATA:
      //THIS EVENT IS NOT FIRERING
      Logger.Info("MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_DATA");
      break;
    case MQTT_EVENT_BEFORE_CONNECT:
      Logger.Info("MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_BEFORE_CONNECT");
      break;
    default:
      Logger.Error("MQTT event UNKNOWN");
      break;
  }
}

static void initializeIoTHubClient()
{
  if (az_result_failed(az_iot_hub_client_init(
          &client,
          az_span_create((uint8_t*)host, strlen(host)),
          az_span_create((uint8_t*)device_id, strlen(device_id)),
          NULL)))
  {
    Logger.Error("Failed initializing Azure IoT Hub client");
    return;
  }

  size_t client_id_length;
  if (az_result_failed(az_iot_hub_client_get_client_id(
          &client, mqtt_client_id, sizeof(mqtt_client_id) - 1, &client_id_length)))
  {
    Logger.Error("Failed getting client id");
    return;
  }

  // Get the MQTT user name used to connect to IoT Hub
  if (az_result_failed(az_iot_hub_client_get_user_name(
          &client, mqtt_username, sizeofarray(mqtt_username), NULL)))
  {
    Logger.Error("Failed to get MQTT clientId, return code");
    return;
  }

  Logger.Info("Client ID: " + String(mqtt_client_id));
  Logger.Info("Username: " + String(mqtt_username));
}

static int initializeMqttClient()
{
  if (sasToken.Generate(SAS_TOKEN_DURATION_IN_MINUTES) != 0)
  {
    Logger.Error("Failed generating SAS token");
    return 1;
  }

  esp_mqtt_client_config_t mqtt_config;
  memset(&mqtt_config, 0, sizeof(mqtt_config));
  mqtt_config.uri = mqtt_broker_uri;
  mqtt_config.port = mqtt_port;
  mqtt_config.client_id = mqtt_client_id;
  mqtt_config.username = mqtt_username;
  mqtt_config.password = (const char*)az_span_ptr(sasToken.Get());
  mqtt_config.keepalive = 30;
  mqtt_config.disable_clean_session = 0;
  mqtt_config.disable_auto_reconnect = false;
  mqtt_config.event_handle = mqtt_event_handler;
  mqtt_config.user_context = NULL;
  mqtt_config.cert_pem = (const char*)ca_pem;

  mqtt_client = esp_mqtt_client_init(&mqtt_config);

  if (mqtt_client == NULL)
  {
    Logger.Error("Failed creating mqtt client");
    return 1;
  }

  esp_err_t start_result = esp_mqtt_client_start(mqtt_client);

  if (start_result != ESP_OK)
  {
    Logger.Error("Could not start mqtt client; error code:" + start_result);
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    Logger.Info("MQTT client started");
    return 0;
  }
}

static uint32_t getEpochTimeInSecs() 
{ 
  return (uint32_t)time(NULL);
}

static int establishConnection()
{
  connectToWiFi();
  initializeTime();
  initializeIoTHubClient();
  (void)initializeMqttClient();
}

void setup() { establishConnection(); }

static void getTelemetryPayload(az_span payload, az_span* out_payload)
{
  az_span original_payload = payload;

  payload = az_span_copy(
      payload, AZ_SPAN_FROM_STR("{ \"deviceId\": \"" IOT_CONFIG_DEVICE_ID "\", \"msgCount\": "));
  (void)az_span_u32toa(payload, telemetry_send_count++, &payload);
  payload = az_span_copy(payload, AZ_SPAN_FROM_STR(" }"));
  payload = az_span_copy_u8(payload, '\0');

  *out_payload = az_span_slice(original_payload, 0, az_span_size(original_payload) - az_span_size(payload));
}

static void sendTelemetry()
{
  az_span telemetry = AZ_SPAN_FROM_BUFFER(telemetry_payload);

  Logger.Info("Sending telemetry ...");

  // The topic could be obtained just once during setup,
  // however if properties are used the topic need to be generated again to reflect the
  // current values of the properties.
  if (az_result_failed(az_iot_hub_client_telemetry_get_publish_topic(
          &client, NULL, telemetry_topic, sizeof(telemetry_topic), NULL)))
  {
    Logger.Error("Failed az_iot_hub_client_telemetry_get_publish_topic");
    return;
  }

  getTelemetryPayload(telemetry, &telemetry);

  if (esp_mqtt_client_publish(
          mqtt_client,
          telemetry_topic,
          (const char*)az_span_ptr(telemetry),
          az_span_size(telemetry),
          MQTT_QOS1,
          DO_NOT_RETAIN_MSG)
      == 0)
  {
    Logger.Error("Failed publishing");
  }
  else
  {
    Logger.Info("Message published successfully");
  }
}

void loop()
{
  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    connectToWiFi();
  }
  else if (sasToken.IsExpired())
  {
    Logger.Info("SAS token expired; reconnecting with a new one.");
    (void)esp_mqtt_client_destroy(mqtt_client);
    initializeMqttClient();
  }
  else if (millis() > next_telemetry_send_time_ms)
  {
    sendTelemetry();
    next_telemetry_send_time_ms = millis() + TELEMETRY_FREQUENCY_MILLISECS;
  }
}
```

COM LOG:

```
11:07:37.286 -> 1970/1/1 00:00:00 [INFO] Connecting to WIFI SSID ELMA
11:07:37.904 -> .....
11:07:39.898 -> 1970/1/1 00:00:02 [INFO] WiFi connected, IP address: 192.168.3.90
11:07:39.898 -> 1970/1/1 00:00:02 [INFO] Setting time using SNTP
11:07:40.399 -> .
11:07:40.399 -> 2021/9/14 08:07:39 [INFO] Time initialized!
11:07:40.399 -> 2021/9/14 08:07:39 [INFO] Client ID: DEVICETEST
11:07:40.399 -> 2021/9/14 08:07:39 [INFO] Username: xxxx
11:07:40.399 -> 2021/9/14 08:07:39 [INFO] 2021/9/14 08:07:39 [INFO] mqtt_event_handler fired!
11:07:40.399 -> 2021/9/14 08:07:39 [INFO] MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_BEFORE_CONNECT
11:07:40.446 -> MQTT client started
11:07:40.446 -> 2021/9/14 08:07:39 [INFO] Sending telemetry ...
11:07:41.954 -> 2021/9/14 08:07:41 [INFO] mqtt_event_handler fired!
11:07:41.954 -> 2021/9/14 08:07:41 [INFO] MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_CONNECTED
11:07:41.954 -> 2021/9/14 08:07:41 [INFO] Message published successfully
11:07:42.268 -> 2021/9/14 08:07:41 [INFO] mqtt_event_handler fired!
11:07:42.268 -> 2021/9/14 08:07:41 [INFO] MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_PUBLISHED
11:07:51.948 -> 2021/9/14 08:07:51 [INFO] Sending telemetry ...
11:07:51.948 -> 2021/9/14 08:07:51 [INFO] Message published successfully
11:07:52.095 -> 2021/9/14 08:07:51 [INFO] mqtt_event_handler fired!
11:07:52.095 -> 2021/9/14 08:07:51 [INFO] MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_PUBLISHED
```

[Azure console to send message to device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNR34.png)

Comment: Why do you expect EVENT_DATA to be called? This happens when you receive a message for a topic you subscribed to. Your code doesn't subscribe to any topics.

Comment: Thank you for the response. If I send a message from device to hub I don't use topic and event MQTT_EVENT_PUBLISHED is fired, so I assumed EVENT_DATA is the event witch is called when a message is send from the Hub to device. How can I make an event for interpreting the data from the Hub in this code?

Comment: The device will only receive messages on topics you subscribe to. That's the way MQTT works. When you send a message from the device you do use a topic - read your code, you publish to whatever the value of `telemetry_topic` is. I'd suggest reading up on MQTT. You don't "make an event", you subscribe to and publish to topics.

Comment: Ok. Now is all clear to me, thank you! I've managed to subscribe to topic and receive a message from Azure IoT Hub and EVENT_DATA is triggered now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as romkey mentioned, I subscribed to C2D topic and after that EVENT_DATA is triggered.

```
#define AZ_IOT_HUB_CLIENT_C2D_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC   "devices/+/messages/devicebound/#"
        
#define MQTT_QOS1 1
    
static void subscribeC2D(){
  if(esp_mqtt_client_subscribe(mqtt_client, AZ_IOT_HUB_CLIENT_C2D_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC, MQTT_QOS1) == 0)
  { 
     Logger.Info("subscribeC2D: Failed to subscribe!");
  }
```

And the call of subscribeC2D() function is in MQTT_EVENT_CONNECTED event.
And the message received from Azure IoT Hub is printed in MQTT_EVENT_DATA event.

```
static esp_err_t mqtt_event_handler(esp_mqtt_event_handle_t event)
{
  switch (event->event_id)
  {
    case MQTT_EVENT_ERROR:
      Logger.Info("MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_ERROR");
      break;
    case MQTT_EVENT_CONNECTED:
      Logger.Info("MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_CONNECTED");  
      subscribeC2D();
      break;
    case MQTT_EVENT_DISCONNECTED:
      Logger.Info("MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_DISCONNECTED");
      break;
    case MQTT_EVENT_SUBSCRIBED:
      Logger.Info("MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_SUBSCRIBED");
      break;
    case MQTT_EVENT_UNSUBSCRIBED:
      Logger.Info("MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_UNSUBSCRIBED");
      break;
    case MQTT_EVENT_PUBLISHED:
      Logger.Info("MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_PUBLISHED");
      break;
    case MQTT_EVENT_DATA:
      Logger.Info("MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_DATA");
      printf("DATA=%.*s\r\n", event->data_len, event->data);
      break;
    case MQTT_EVENT_BEFORE_CONNECT:
      Logger.Info("MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_BEFORE_CONNECT");
      break;
    default:
      Logger.Error("MQTT event UNKNOWN");
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why does this code only work for AZ_IOT_HUB_CLIENT_C2D_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC?  The event handler does not even seem to fire for subscriptions to AZ_IOT_HUB_CLIENT_TWIN_PATCH_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC or   AZ_IOT_HUB_CLIENT_METHODS_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC